# Image not showing when using PHP to link to SRC

Tags: php, html, image, filepath

Trying to use php to link to an image in a different folder than the file I am currently in but the image isn't showing.

Here's the path file:

```
<?php
if (!defined("ROOT_PATH")) define ("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
if (!defined("BASE_URL")) define ("BASE_URL", "http://localhost/stnresp");
?>
```

Here's the code I am using at the moment:

```
<div class="logo-image">
  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/index.php'; ?>"><img class="header-logo" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH . '/assets/images/stn-logo-cropped.png'; ?>" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

I can't understand why the root path isn't taking the link to the root directory and then through to the image? What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realpath` defines the physical path of the file, instead the `src` attribute of the image needs url path.

In your case you have to use `BASE_URL` instead of `ROOT_PATH`:

```
<div class="logo-image">
    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/index.php'; ?>"><img class="header-logo" src="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/assets/images/stn-logo-cropped.png'; ?>" alt=""></a>
</div>
```